# git subtree pull unknown option `allow-unrelated-histories'

Tags: git

При попытке сделать `git subtree pull ... --allow-unrelated-histories` вылетает ошибка

> unknown option **`allow-unrelated-histories'**

без этого флага соответственно

> fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте у себя версию Git, выполнив команду `git --version`

Дело в том, что опция `--allow-unrelated-histories` была добавлена в версии Git 2.9, соответственно, если ваша версия ниже необходимой, то такой опции просто нет.
Эта опция обозначена в [Release note Git 2.9](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68).

То, что у вас по умолчанию поставилась не последняя версия Git - нормальное явление, потому что Git распространяется Lts релизами. Например, у меня в крайней версии MacOS Mojave 10.14.3 стоит версия Git 2.17.2 и искомая опция также не поддерживается.

С обновлением Git до не lts версий связана одна сложность, так как оно доступны только в формате исходного кода.

Похожий вопрос на [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356766/unknown-option-allow-unrelated-histories), если захочется почитать подробней.

Comment: на mac почему-то не ставится 2.9

Comment: да, у меня c make тоже не собирается. Но в целом, проблема с  --allow-unrelated-histories именно из-за версии гита

Comment: не `make`, a `mac` - `MacBook`

Comment: git на MAC собирается по средствам утилиты make, которая у меня ошибку выдает, потому что не может найти нужных библиотек

Comment: у вас случайно в subtree, для котором вы пытаетесь делать pull нет локальных коммитов, которые вы не залили в удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: В общем пришел синьор и все порешал - я уже не знаю как) Решал он на линуксе, поэтому есть большая вероятность, что он просто запустил ту же команду и все залилось

Comment: Тут же можно скачать свежий git https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: @AlexeyTen там последняя версия 2.21, а нужна 2.9. Которая только исходниками идет

Comment: 2.21 это сильно свежее, чем 2.9. Зачем вам версия трёхлетней давности?